# проверка пароле в ларавель

Tags: laravel

как можно сверить пароли пользователей? новый с текущим в базе?

```
$passuser = Hash::make($request->password);
        $admin = User::where('email', $request->email)
                        ->where('password', $passuser)
                        ->first();
        if ($admin && $admin == 1) return view('admin.home');
        return view('admin.login')->withErrors('Неверный пароль');
```

Comment: а что не получается?

Comment: добавил в вопрос свой код

Comment: добавил код это отлично. Ну а не работает-то что? Ошибка? Не находит? или наоборот находит чего не должен? Вопрос-то в чём?

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/hashing

Метод `Hash::check(<обычная строка>, <хешированная строка>)` позволяет проверить, соответствует ли данная строка обычного текста заданному хешу.

```
if (Hash::check('plain-text', $hashedPassword)) {
    // Пароли соответствуют...
}
```

В Вашем случает получаете по почте

```
$admin = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
```

И проверяете пароль:

```
if (!$admin) {
    // Не нашло по почте
}

if (Hash::check($request->password, $admin->password)) {
    // Пароли соответствуют...
}
```

Comment: а если так делаю то выдает хеш другой, почему так?
$passuser = Hash::make($request->password);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24381316/laravel-4-hashing-same-password-gives-different-values/24381464#24381464 
https://mnshankar.wordpress.com/2014/03/29/laravel-hash-make-explained/